# AngularFireAuth.auth.signInAnonymously not returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have the following anonymousLogin method in my authorization service:

```
anonymousLogin() {
    console.log("anonymousLogin entered");
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
     .then((credential) => {
       console.log("success inside callback for signInAnonymously");
       // this.authState = credential;
       this.updateUserData(credential.user);
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

I can confirm that the `console.log("anonymousLogin entered");` line prints in the console, but neither the  `console.log("success inside callback for signInAnonymously");` *nor* the `console.log(error));` line print in the console. I'm not sure where in the ether my login attempt was lost, nor am I sure how to troubleshoot from here. I welcome any advice.

Version info

My package.json contents:

```
{
  "name": "population-fragmentation",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.585.0",
    "compass-mixins": "^0.12.10",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "firebase": "^7.5.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.7",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "pet-names": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "sass": "^1.23.7",
    "stripe": "^7.14.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.49",
    "@types/stripe": "^7.13.12",
    "@types/stripe-checkout": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.9",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.8.1"
  }
}
```

** Screenshots **
[image: Screen Shot 2019-12-06 at 11 08 35 PM]

(I have enabled anonymous login on my firebase project)

Comment: Out of curiousity, what do you get when you add `console.log('AuthIsStateResolved: ' + this.afAuth.auth.isStateResolved_);` just above your `return` statement?

Comment: @samthecodingman: 'AuthIsStateResolved: undefined'

Comment: And after re-compiling, I get a compiler error: `ERROR in src/app/auth.service.ts(62,60): error TS2339: Property 'isStateResolved_' does not exist on type 'Auth'`

Comment: Ah shoot. I forgot the firebase-js-sdk is minified. [`isStateResolved_`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/fa3fc0fa8760cf159e47b7860e00861205dbf55a/packages/auth/src/auth.js#L140-L141) is a private property of `FirebaseAuth` so it's variable name will be changed. I was trying to determine if the internal [`redirectStateIsReady_`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/fa3fc0fa8760cf159e47b7860e00861205dbf55a/packages/auth/src/auth.js#L1612-L1617) promise was not resolving properly. Because the promise seems to be returned by `signInAnonymously()`, but isn't resolving.

Comment: @samthecodingman darn! Any other leads/strategies I could look into?

Comment: OMG turning my computer off and then on again resolved the issue!! But.... how?!